# Not able to control real robot using MoveIt!

Tags: ros, schunk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to moveit and ROS. I have Schunk Lwa4p arm for which I created moveit config package (using set up assistant). But I am struggling to control the real arm from moveit.

Upon running `moveit_planning_execution.launch` and clicking on Execute button in RViz, I got following errors:

```
[ INFO] [1458896804.810438377]: Waiting for operationmode service to become available
[ERROR] [1458896804.974349026]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: arm/joint_trajectory_controller
[ INFO] [1458896805.079746996]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1458896805.119044800]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
```

and

```
[ INFO] [1458896900.940527967]: Waiting for operationmode service to become available
[ INFO] [1458896901.933728220]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[ WARN] [1458896901.933887039]: Execution of motions should always start at the robot's current state. Ignoring the state supplied as start state in the motion planning request
[ INFO] [1458896901.933944449]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[ INFO] [1458896901.935989122]: No planner specified. Using default.
[ INFO] [1458896901.936155554]: LBKPIECE1: Attempting to use default projection.
[ INFO] [1458896901.938471980]: LBKPIECE1: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1458896901.941578311]: Waiting for operationmode service to become available
[ INFO] [1458896902.432168629]: LBKPIECE1: Created 184 (87 start + 97 goal) states in 176 cells (86 start (86 on boundary) + 90 goal (90 on boundary))
[ INFO] [1458896902.434038979]: Solution found in 0.496061 seconds
[ INFO] [1458896902.434911366]: SimpleSetup: Path simplification took 0.000396 seconds and changed from 167 to 2 states
[ INFO] [1458896902.440256320]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[ERROR] [1458896902.440616352]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ arm_1_joint arm_2_joint arm_3_joint arm_4_joint arm_5_joint arm_6_joint ]
[ERROR] [1458896902.440879514]: Known controllers and their joints:
[ERROR] [1458896902.441217545]: Apparently trajectory initialization failed
[ INFO] [1458896902.942730273]: Waiting for operationmode service to become available
```

Following are the additional details:

1. I am using ROS Indigo devel on Ubuntu 14.04
2. Planning in RViz was successful and it displayed the planned path.
3. rostopic doesn't list the topics related to moveit_simple_controller_manager
4. `moveit_planning_execution.launch` used: It is similar to the one given at http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=moveit_planning_execution.launch.txt
5. `controllers.yaml` used:

   controller_manager_ns: moveit_simple_controller_manager
   controller_list:
   - name: "arm"
   action_ns: joint_trajectory_controller
   type: FollowJointTrajectory
   default: true
   joints: [arm_1_joint, arm_2_joint, arm_3_joint, arm_4_joint, arm_5_joint, arm_6_joint]

Please help me on how to resolve this and control my robot using moveit.
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230140/not-able-to-control-real-robot-using-moveit!/) by [Nivedita T](https://answers.ros.org/users/25697/nivedita-t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally, I could solve my problem:

1. By mapping MoveIt!'s controller manager **moveit_simple_controller_manager** to **joint_trajectory_controller**, the original controller manager of Robot.
2. Once mapped, it has to be called with the appropriate name **/arm/joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory** instead of **joint_trajectory_controller** in controllers.yaml.

---

Originally posted by [Nivedita T](https://answers.ros.org/users/25697/nivedita-t/) with karma: 21 on 2016-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) on 2016-06-16**:
Hi! Can you explain in detail how did you did the above mapping?

I have followed the same procedure as detailed by you in the question above but am getting the error: Parameter:'`moveit_controller_manager' not specified. Have no clue where am I going wrong. Will be grateful to you if you can help.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-12-28**:
I have the same problem. Topic list shows follow_trajectory_controllers action server is ready. But action client from MoveIt! side doesn't show up. I got the same errors:
`Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specify joints.` 
Can you detail what topic to map?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me, the problem was in the launch file where an argument was not being specified

This error came while running ur5 (universal robot package) with moveit and rviz.

the **sim:= true** was missing while calling the command

```
$ roslaunch ur5_moveit_config ur5_moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=true
```

Inside the launch file, the "sim" argument actually does the remapping that @Nivedita T above mentions.

---

Originally posted by [harshitsureka](https://answers.ros.org/users/29428/harshitsureka/) with karma: 11 on 2017-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1